# Is "the" used in the names of stadiums?

Tags: usage, definite-article

Is "the" used in the names of stadiums? For example.

- Etihad or **the** Etihad
- Wembley or **the** Wembley
- White Hart Lane or **the** White Hart Lane
- Old Trafford or **the** Old Trafford
- Stamford Bridge or **the** Stamford Bridge
- London stadium or **the** London stadium, and so on.

What about stadium names outside the English Premier league? Do they take "the" or not? How do you determine them?

Comment: Have you tried googling the names with "the"? What did you find?

Comment: Generally no, one exception I can think of is a stadium which opened as "The Ballpark in Arlington" (when naming rights were sold and the facility was renamed, the new name apparently did not include "the"). By the way all the stadiums you listed are foreign.

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin - 'foreign' depends on where you live. The very nature of Stack Exchange is that we're all from different places around the world. As it happens, none of those places are 'foreign' to me :P

Comment: @DoneWithThis. How about stadium names outside the English Premier league? Do they take a "the" or not? For example: San Siro, Nou Camp, Bernabeu, etc.

Comment: You'd have to ask the locals. I've never heard of any of those, but google tells me one is in Italy, two in Spain - which makes them or their usage not about English at all.

Comment: @DoneWithThis - up until now I had been under the impression that the people to whom those stadiums would not be foreign actually had a keen sense of humor.

Comment: [The official website](https://www.sansirostadium.com/en/) calls itself "the San Siro Stadium". But I'm not convinced this is good English. The Guardian seems to call it just "San Siro". Although you might say "the San Siro stadium" to differentiate it from "the San Siro practice pitches".

Answer (score 1):

If the full, *proper name* of the stadium includes the word 'stadium', then the definite article would not be needed (unless of course the article is also part of the proper name). '*Wembley Stadium*' is an example of this. It is commonly abbreviated to 'Wembley', but context would be needed because Wembley is also the name of the area of London where the stadium is located.

If the stadium has a name attributed to it, such as the name of a sponsor, then the definite article would be used. '*The Etihad Stadium*' is an example of this, being sponsored by Etihad Airways. Saying 'The Ethihad Stadium' is like saying 'the stadium sponsored by Ethihad', in a similar way that 'the Isle of Wight Ferry' means the ferry that serves the Isle of Wight.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But people sometimes omit the word stadium and just say "the Etihad", Is it the same as "Emirates Stadium?" What about stadium names outside the English Premier league? Do they also take "the?" For example: Bernabeu, Nou Camp, San Siro, Alianz Arena, etc.

Comment: @Nyambek that's not uncommon, we love to abbreviate things. And we don't always call things by the name that we are supposed to. I've explained the proper names - follow native speakers for shortenings and nicknames.

Comment: I read live text commetary on the Sun and find "Stamford Bridge" to be abbreviated to "the Bridge". Also, "White Hart Lane is abbreviated to "the Lane". With 15 minutes to play, it's game on at **the Bridge**. Why use "the" in this case?

Comment: @Nyambek well you're talking about nicknames again. This is very common with football team names, too. Fans of Blackpool FC chant "up **the** mighty Pool!". Other teams may get called 'the reds' or 'the blues'. Your original question was about proper names, not nicknames. Why is Dwayne Johnson called 'The Rock' and not simply 'Rock'? When it's a nickname you can call yourself whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain what "up" means in "Fans of Blackpool FC chant "**up** the mighty Pool!

Comment: @Nyambek with the greatest respect, that isn't part of your original question and comments should remain on topic. Have you got a dictionary? You'll find 'up' has many, many uses and I'm sure you'll find the meaning if you're familiar with this usage.

Answer (score -1):

London, Wembley and Old Trafford are place names, White Hart Lane and Stamford Bridge are locations near to the football grounds in question. We wouldn't use an article with these names.

The Etihad Stadium is named after the company which currently sponsors it. It *does* use the definite article.

Comment: What about stadium names outside the English Premier league? Do they take "the" or not? For example. San Siro, Nou Camp, Bernabeu, etc.

Comment: I'm not a football fan, so I don't know how overseas grounds are referred to. Try looking them up in English-language resources online.

Comment: But the Ethiad Stadium was previously known as "The City of Manchester Stadium", and that's the name of a place, so your rule is incorrect.

Comment: @Astralbee - I did wonder about [the] London Stadium (which I didn't remember hearing of before), comparing it to 'the London Eye' etc., but websites seem to refer to it without the article.